# If $z = \text{Re}(z) + i \text{Im}(z)$, express $z(\bar z +1)$ in terms of $\text{Re}(z) + \text{Im}(z)$.

Tags: complex-numbers

So far, I know that $\text{Re}(z)$ and $\text{Im}(z)$ are real numbers. However, if I expand

$z(\bar z +1) = \lvert z^2 \rvert + z = x^2 + y^2 + x + iy$

Does this mean $\text{Im}(z)$ equals to all the $y$ terms meaning $\text{Im}(z) = y^2 + y $? And $\text{Re}(z) = x^2 + x$?

I have a doubt as $\text{Re}(z)$ means the real portion (along the $x$-axis). Hence should $\text{Re}(z) = x^2 + y^2 + x$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have introduced $x$ to represent $\Re(z)$ and $y$ to represent $\Im(z)$, so just replace $x$ and $y$ in your expression $x^2+y^2+x+iy$.  If the question instead were asking about the real and imaginary parts of $z(\bar{z}+1)$, they would be
\begin{align}
\Re(z(\bar{z}+1)) &= x^2+y^2+x \\
\Im(z(\bar{z}+1)) &= y
\end{align}